# Reserved Keywords in column Active Record c#

Tags: c#, activerecord, reserved-words

I have a mssql database where a table has a column with the name "key".

Now I want the create the ActiveRecord class for this table and I get the error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Key'.

Key is a reserved Keyword and ActiveRecord generate a query like:

```
SELECT top 1 this_.Key as Key0_0_ FROM PlaceHolder this_
```

So it doesn't work. Is there a way, where I can fix this error without any changes on the dbmodel?

My workaround at the moment is:

```
[PrimaryKey(PrimaryKeyType.Assigned, "[Key]")]
```

But I think it isn't the perfect solution.

Comment: Changing your column name with a _non-reserved_ word?

Comment: i have a database with a reserved column name as well (since it was converted from a older database) and if i want to use that one I simply have to call `PLAN` as `[PLAN]` and it just works. So that might be the case here to?

Comment: This is one the reasons I always use the table name as prefix to the column names.

Comment: @maam27 Yes, you can escape your reserved words with `[]` but in this case I think (sounds like) `ActiveRecord` get's the table name exactly what it is and user can't put `[]` directly in it's query.

Comment: Don't judge me.
It's an old database filled with storedprocedure and functions. So I can't change it to a non-reserved word without a hugh change on different storedprocedures and functions. And I think there are also different excel files with a reference to this database...
I hoped there would be a better solution.